# Would like Autofac to not register any interface that has more than one implementation

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm currently testing Autofac for our company.

We'd like to have the following rules:

1. If an interface has been implemented only once, then add it automatically using the builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes (see below).
2. Otherwise, we need to make sure to manually write the rule that will decide which implementation is the 'default' implementation.

I have the following code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly
    .Load("Lunch.Service")).As(t => t.GetInterfaces()[0]);
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLoggerService>()
    .As<ILoggerService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterModule(new DestinationModule());
builder.RegisterType<TransportationService>()
    .As<ITransportationService>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Right now, it's working, but it decides which the first implementation is and will automatically create that. We'd like to make that a manual process and have an error thrown if we don't manually create the 'rule'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
cb.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).Where(type =>
{
    var implementations = type.GetInterfaces();

    if (implementations.Length > 0)
    {
        var iface = implementations[0];

        var implementers =
            from t in assembly.GetTypes()
            where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(iface)
            select t;

        return implementers.Count() == 1;
    }

    return false;
})
.As(t => t.GetInterfaces()[0]);
```

This will register all implementations where only a single implementer exists, and ignore interfaces with multiple implementations so you can register them manually. Note that I don't claim this is efficient in any way (depending on the number of services, you may want to look at caching implementers for example).

Comment: "Note that I don't claim this is efficient in any way". I hardly ever encountered the performance of the registration phase to be a problem and iterating over all types in an assembly is normally reasonably fast. This code you show, does not negatively impact runtime performance (the time it takes to resolve an instance), so there shouldn't be any problem with this.

Comment: thanks. I'll check this out. Wondering if the use case makes sense. Basically, we have the issue with so many references that we sometimes don't realize why things are happening and it's because the wrong class got injected. So this would make it default for everything that has one, and if there are more than one, then we need to manually create the case.

Comment: Do you have a legitimate reason for multiple implementers to be found, or is it really more of an error condition that you're finding multiples? If it's really an error, or at least an unexpected condition, perhaps you should really be throwing an exception or logging an error when multiple implementations are found (as this may imply you've got a reference to an assembly that really shouldn't be deployed)? Or is it really that you have multiple implementations available and you need to manually pick one based on configuration? If it's the latter, this seems like a reasonable use case.

Comment: It's that I have multiple implementations available and need to pick one based on configuration. Aka. We have a web service and website. The website needs one implmentation, and the web service needs another. But if I forget to put a special case in, then it will always default. I'd prefer not to have the default and get the error. Then I'll add the special case in for both sites.

Comment: In that case, it seems to me like this is a reasonable solution to your problem - it worked in a simple test project - how'd it do on yours?