# autofac how to select an implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

I try to understand Autofac in a MVC3 Application.
When I have several implementations of an interface, how and where can I decide which one I want to use? 
Or is it "bad" to have more than one implementations?

Comment: It's very logical to have multiple implementations of a single interface, having just a single implementation is possibly a violation of the [Reused Abstraction Principle](http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

Comment: Ok but how I decide with autofac which one is the one to take?

Comment: Perhaps this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486342/would-like-autofac-to-not-register-any-interface-that-has-more-than-one-implenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Many implementations of the same service can be differentiated using names and keys.](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices)